# Eclipse using WebSphere Liberty Server error initializer

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-liberty

I've seem to have exhausted researching and what I can check or change.  Maybe someone will have some insight.  I have a WebSphere Application Server Liberty running on Eclipse.  At server startup it starts initializing .jar files then  Errors start.

Resource could not be installed or FrameworkEvent Error java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Launching xFrameworkX (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.4/wlp-1.0.7.cl50420141211-1039) 
    on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_71-b15 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server xFrameworkX has been launched.

    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for application`enter code here`s. 

[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): 
     http://xxxxx.netgear.com:9080/xxxx/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application xConfigWeb started in 2.302 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): 
     http://Y111-r90h3jny.netgear.com:9080/rest/api/
19  xPersistentUnit  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-6] openjpa.Runtime - 
         Could not create the optional validation provider. 
         Reason returned: "A default ValidatorFactory could not be created."
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application xConfigurationApp started in 4.659 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server xFrameworkX is ready to run a smarter planet.
Reloading logging configuration from 
      C:\-----xFramework\x-config\log4j.properties
957  xPersistentUnit  INFO   Extender: 2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.2.3-SNAPSHOT
1652  xPersistentUnit  INFO   Extender: 2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - 
16/02/07 00:50:53 INFO [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.CoreCacheInitializer: 
    Loading cache for System Properties
16/02/07 00:50:54 INFO [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.CoreInitializer: 
     x deployment started at location: C:----xFrameworkX\x-autodeploy
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.BundleInitializer: 
   Found bundle at location:Collectorx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.BundleInitializer: 
     Found bundle at location:Forwarderx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-1]initializer.BundleInstaller: 
    Registering bundle at the following URI: 
    file:-----servers/xFrameworkX/x-autodeploy/Collectorx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.BundleInitializer: 
    Found bundle at location:GenericListenerx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [Blueprint Extender: 2]initializer.BundleInitializer: 
    Found bundle at location:Mapperx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-3]initializer.BundleInstaller: 
    Registering bundle at the following URI: 
    file:------servers/xFrameworkX/x-autodeploy/GenericListenerx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-2]initializer.BundleInstaller: 
    Registering bundle at the following URI: 
     file:-------servers/xFrameworkX/x-autodeploy/Forwarderx.jar
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-4]initializer.BundleInstaller: 
    Registering bundle at the following URI: 
    file--------/servers/xFrameworkX/x-autodeploy/Mapperx.jar
**[ERROR   ] Resource could not be installed**
     Coordination "xConfigurationApp-4" with ID "12" has failed.
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-3]initializer.BundleInstaller: 
     Retry (1) - Waiting for x: null to be available.
**[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: FrameworkEvent ERROR** 
     Bundle:org.eclipse.osgi(id=0) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.impl.GlobalPersistenceManager$2.addingBundle(GlobalPersistenceManager.java:311)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.Y.gts.core.initializer.BundleInstaller.run(BundleInstaller.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Event:org.osgi.framework.FrameworkEvent[source=org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.7.cl50420141211-1039 [0]] 
[ERROR   ] Resource could not be installed
Coordination "xConfigurationApp-4" with ID "13" has failed.
16/02/07 00:50:54 DEBUG [pool-5-thread-1]initializer.BundleInstaller: Retry 
     (1) - Waiting for x: null to be available.
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: FrameworkEvent ERROR Bundle:org.eclipse.osgi(id=0) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.impl.GlobalPersistenceManager$2.addingBundle(GlobalPersistenceManager.java:311)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.Y.gts.core.initializer.BundleInstaller.run(BundleInstaller.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Event:org.osgi.framework.FrameworkEvent[source=org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.7.cl50420141211-1039 [0]]
```

Comment: Are you using "13" as an ID somewhere in the Liberty configuration?

Comment: @nitind That "13" is just an internal/auto-generated ID for an internal mechanism in the Liberty runtime.

Comment: The surface error is an internal problem in the Liberty runtime, and you should open a PMR with IBM.  The problem might be caused by your application doing something wrong, but that should never surface as a NullPointerException from the runtime.